# i can't find the weblogic.xml file in my 12c application

Tags: oracle, jsp, jakarta-ee, weblogic12c

i have a jee application previously deployed on oc4j,im trying to migrate to weblogic 12c server.i've recreated the project with jdev 12. (i created a new project and progressivly added the old project's parts). the problem is that my jsp page don't show up(except the index page).the application is redirected to an URL but nothing appears on the screen.i been thinking maybe the problem is about the deploymet descriptors,since the weblogic.xml is not generated with the project. 
should i write it by myself? any ideas? thanx

Answer (score 0):

It is totally fine to create weblogic.xml yourself inside WEB-INF directory. And yes, this might be a root cause of your problem, since weblogic.xml holds jsp and container descriptors.